Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
I have an issue that I haven't resolved yet. So I'd like to make a post to get support from everyone.
I have a components folder, and inside it, I have a root file (index) and a file named UnborderCollapse:
index file:
export { default as UnborderCollapse } from './UnborderCollapse'

and UnborderCollapse.tsx file:
const UnborderCollapse = (props: Props) => {...some code here...}

UnborderCollapse.Item = Item
UnborderCollapse.Actions = Actions
UnborderCollapse.LeftGroup = LeftGroup
UnborderCollapse.RightGroup = RightGroup

export default UnborderCollapse

When I run the unit test, I get an error:
FAIL [.....path to file]
  ● Test suite failed to run
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')


      at Object.UnborderCollapse (src/components/index.ts:272:30)

Could someone help me and explain why this issue happens? Thank you very much !!!

What is line 272 of src/components/index.ts?

It is this code: export { default as UnborderCollapse } from './UnborderCollapse'

I can't seem to reproduce this error from the code in your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-psmxfb?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FUnborderCollapse.tsx How the the code in that stackblitz differ from what you have?

export { default as UnborderCollapse } from './UnborderCollapse' I believe this will try to cast default as UnborderCollapse  which is wrong, If you wish to export all components from that folder through the index file, It's better to follow barrel export for those React Components

@M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA if that file has a default export, then this line simply re-exports that default exported as a named export, which is technically fine.

change export { default as UnborderCollapse } from './UnborderCollapse' to export * from './UnborderCollapse I think this is the proper way to use barrel export.
